# Create a data.frame of pairwise distances between points with a third variable

Tags: r

I'm trying to take data with spatial coordinates (x and y) and a variable (z). I want to get the pairwise distance between each point and the corresponding values for z. I have that in the example below starting with foo and ending with bar. This seems like a very inelegant approach. Is there a better way that springs to mind?

```
library(dplyr)
foo <- data.frame(id = LETTERS[1:5],
                  x = c(3,1,4,1,5),
                  y = c(9,2,6,5,3),
                  z = c(5,8,9,7,9))
fooDist <- as.matrix(dist(foo[,2:3]))
colnames(fooDist) <- rownames(fooDist) <- foo$id
xy <- t(combn(colnames(fooDist), 2))
bar <- data.frame(xy, dist=fooDist[xy])
names(bar)[1:2] <- c("id_1","id_2")
bar$z_1 <- inner_join(bar,foo,by = c("id_1"="id"))$z
bar$z_2 <- inner_join(bar,foo,by = c("id_2"="id"))$z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
left_join(foo, foo, join_by(id < id), suffix = c('1', '2')) %>%
   na.omit() %>%
   mutate( dist = sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2), .keep = 'unused')
   id1 z1 id2 z2     dist
1    A  5   B  8 7.280110
2    A  5   C  9 3.162278
3    A  5   D  7 4.472136
4    A  5   E  9 6.324555
5    B  8   C  9 5.000000
6    B  8   D  7 3.000000
7    B  8   E  9 4.123106
8    C  9   D  7 3.162278
9    C  9   E  9 3.162278
10   D  7   E  9 4.472136
```

---

```
as.data.frame.table(as.matrix(dist(foo[,2:3])), responseName = 'dist')|>
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE)|>
   subset(Var1 > Var2) |>
   transform(id_1 = foo$id[Var2], id_2 = foo$id[Var1], 
             z_1 = foo$z[Var2], z_2 = foo$z[Var1], 
             Var1 = NULL, Var2 = NULL)

       dist id_1 id_2 z_1 z_2
2  7.280110    A    B   5   8
3  3.162278    A    C   5   9
4  4.472136    A    D   5   7
5  6.324555    A    E   5   9
8  5.000000    B    C   8   9
9  3.000000    B    D   8   7
10 4.123106    B    E   8   9
14 3.162278    C    D   9   7
15 3.162278    C    E   9   9
20 4.472136    D    E   7   9
```

---

```
as.data.frame.table(as.matrix(dist(foo[,2:3])), responseName = 'dist')|>
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE)|>
   subset(Var1 > Var2) |>
   transform(a=foo[Var2, c('id', 'z')], b=foo[Var1, c('id', 'z')])

   Var1 Var2     dist a.id a.z b.id b.z
2     2    1 7.280110    A   5    B   8
3     3    1 3.162278    A   5    C   9
4     4    1 4.472136    A   5    D   7
5     5    1 6.324555    A   5    E   9
8     3    2 5.000000    B   8    C   9
9     4    2 3.000000    B   8    D   7
10    5    2 4.123106    B   8    E   9
14    4    3 3.162278    C   9    D   7
15    5    3 3.162278    C   9    E   9
20    5    4 4.472136    D   7    E   9
```

Answer (score 1):

Elegance is sort of subjective perception, definitely up to your feeling, but you can try the code below

```
cbind(
    do.call(
        rbind,
        combn(1:nrow(foo), 2, \(k) with(
            foo,
            data.frame(id = t(id[k]), z = t(z[k]))
        ), simplify = FALSE)
    ),
    dist = c(dist(foo[, 2:3]))
)
```

which gives

```
   id.1 id.2 z.1 z.2     dist
1     A    B   5   8 7.280110
2     A    C   5   9 3.162278
3     A    D   5   7 4.472136
4     A    E   5   9 6.324555
5     B    C   8   9 5.000000
6     B    D   8   7 3.000000
7     B    E   8   9 4.123106
8     C    D   9   7 3.162278
9     C    E   9   9 3.162278
10    D    E   7   9 4.472136
```